# Unable to find any supported Python versions

Tags: python, flask, vercel, portfolio

I want to deploy my portfolio on Vercel, but I'm getting this error:

```
 Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
 Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
 Cloning completed: 909.067ms
 Running "vercel build"
 Vercel CLI 33.6.2
 Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions.
```

I downloaded the new python 3.12 update, but it didn't do anything, in my pyvenv.cfg file, the version is 3.11. Then I changed it to 12, but nothing changed. I'm using flask.